# Identify reply mail of which mail category using internet header info

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

i am working on an application which send email with custom internet header info in it which is used to identify mail type it has been sent.

for example, if i sending for option A it will be my custom tag with value 1 or if i send for option B it will be my custom tag with value 2.

if the customer reply or forward to that mail, i need to identify for which mail type is replied or forwarded (i.e., it is for option A or Option B). so i need to carry the custom internet header info in reply or forward mail also. any option available to carry the custom internet header in reply or forward mail or is there any alternative approach to do this

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already developed the part where customer can select the options.

Reading mime headers you can try this: [Get email Headers from an Outlook MailItem](http://www.lessanvaezi.com/email-headers-from-outlook-mailitem/)